# Discrete Math: Combinatorics and recursion

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

3. Let S be a set of size 37, and let x, y, and z be three distinct elements of S. How many
   subsets of S are there that contain x and y, but do not contain z?

(a) $2^{33}$

(b) $2^{34}$

(c) $2^{35}$

(d) $2^{37} − 2^{35} − 2^{36}$

(d) none of the above

Why is it B) I thought there is size 37 so it is 37 - 2
Is it because there is size 37 and for x and y; you do 37-2. but you cannot have z so you minus another 1. so 37-2-1=34; $2^{34}$

12. The Fibonacci numbers are defined as follows: f0 = 0, f1 = 1, and fn = fn−1 + fn−2 for
    n ≥ 2.
    Consider again the recursive algorithm Fib, which takes as input an integer n ≥ 0:

    Algorithm Fib(n):

    if n = 0 or n = 1

    then f = n

    else f = Fib(n − 1) + Fib(n − 2)

    endif;

    return f

For n ≥ 3, run algorithm Fib(n) and let an be the number of times that Fib(2) is called.
Which of the following is true?

(a) For n ≥ 3, $a_n = f_{n−1}$

(b) For n ≥ 3, $a_n = f_n$

(c) For n ≥ 3, $a_n = f_{n+1}$

(d) For n ≥ 3, $a_n = −1 + f_n$

So if it is n = 3 i will call fib(2) 1 time and if n = 4 then fib(2) is called 2 times

How do I put this into an equation like above?

Answer (score 0):

The intuition of the first one is fine. You can see it very clearly by doing the bijection between subsets and binary strings, there you have constant values on the position $x,y$ and $z$.
For the second one do some recursion, you have counted it to $3$ and $4$, if you call Fib($5$), then the times you call Fib($2$) is the times you called it in Fib($5-1$) plus the times it is called in Fib($5-2$). In general, $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ with your basic cases, you can conclude $a_n=f_{n-1}$.